# 'decodeHex(char[])' in 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, hex

I am creating a function in Java to append some data to Excel file. For defining color properties to a cell. I have written a function:

```
String rgbS = "9BC2E6";
byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS);
```

but it does not work for me and gives error. The error message is:

> 'decodeHex(char[])' in 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String)'

Can anyone help me out?

Here is the screenshot of Hex.java class for reference:
[Hex.java class screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEbcW.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `int rgbI = 0x98C2E6;` would be more direct, if code could be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decodeHex method needs a char array and you're passing a String. You should convert your string into a char array.

Comment: You might add s solution too: `byte[] rgbB = Hex.decodeHex(rgbS.toCharArray());`